# Controlling one audio file with two links

Tags: css, audio-player

I want to control the start and pause of one audio-file in two ways:

1. the regular controls, that show with the option "control"
2. A javascript behind a small icon floating on the top left part of
   the screen.

So, if someone starts the `mp3` via the image OR the controls, it should play and should either be paused by clicking on the icon in the top left, or on the regular player.

But it doesn't work. All I manage to do at the moment is two player, that will play the same mp3, but clicking on one doesn't affect playback of the other one...

My code so far

```js
//<![CDATA[
    window.onload=function() {
      
  document.getElementById("playAudio").addEventListener("click", function() {
            var audio=document.getElementById('testAudio');
            if(this.className=='is-playing') {
                this.className="";
                this.innerHTML="<i class='float'><img class='bildpur-s pur' src='https://www.liesenfeld.de/WP/images/play-small.gif'></i>";
                audio.pause();
                
            }
            else {
                this.className="is-playing";
                this.innerHTML="<i class='float'><img class='bildpur-s pur' src='https://www.liesenfeld.de/WP/images/pause-small.gif'></i>";
                audio.play();
            }
        }
        );
    } //]]>
```

```css
.float {
        position: fixed;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        top: -8px;
        left: 0px;
        background-color: rgba(182, 149, 105, 0.8);
        color: #FFF;
        border-radius: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
        z-index: 41000;
        color: #fff4e3;
        line-height: 0.8;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .pur {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0;
    }
```

```html
<p><audio id="testAudio" src="https://www.liesenfeld.de/medis/beitrag-erotikmassage.mp3" hidden=""></audio><a id="playAudio" href="#"><i class="float" title="Klicke hier um den Text zu hören"><img class="bildpur-s pur" src="https://www.liesenfeld.de/WP/images/play-small.gif"></i></a></p>
<br><br>
Both the triangle on the top<br>
AND the player below should control the same playback<br>
ATM hitting both triangles will start TWO seperate playbacks.
<p><audio id="testAudio" src="https://www.liesenfeld.de/medis/beitrag-erotikmassage.mp3" controls></audio><a id="playAudio" href="#"><i title="Klicke hier um den Text zu hören"></i></a></p>
```

Comment: Don't use the same id for both audio tags. use different id and change your code according to that